# Should I have traces within Alloy "submodules"

Tags: alloy

This is a "best practices" question, rather than a question on the language itself.

I am working on breaking my project into modules, following the advice in the Software Abstraction book. I have signatures, facts and predicates for each small piece of my larger model in their own separate files. I have them properly included in my "main file".

For a few of the smaller modules, I found it useful to "prove out" the design by adding traces at that level. Traces are just facts though, so when I run the traces I have created in my main file, I get odd results ("two time steps at once", etc).

I see two options (after either of which I can just complete my main file traces):

1. comment out the traces in "sub modules"
2. make the "sub module" traces a bit less restrictive to allow for the option for *nothing* to happen

Do either of these look correct? Or is this usually done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best things I discovered while using Alloy is to not use facts but use predicates instead. You can control which predicates are active in a run or assert. You can always combine predicates so it is not much of an inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Peter. I just implemented this a few minutes ago, and this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Facts are for things that could not possible be false, predicates for things that probably shouldn't be false

Comment: @Hovercouch you are right but the problem is that they are global. Using predicates allows me to pick the exact predicates I want to test in a run or check. Especially  for traces it is nice to have alternative traces in the same model.